# ODOO 9 the "read more" link is not working in the message?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

when a message is too long odoo displays a read more link that you have click on it to show the full text of the message.

this link is only working on a local installation on my computer (localhost:8069) but on a remote adress is not working (192.168.1.1:8069).

in the chrome consol of the developer tools I see this msg :

> " Can't find "td.oe-actions" when extending template
>   One2Many.listview " in this file : web.assets_common.js:2482

I'm using odoo 9, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem resolved by udating to the last version of odoo 9 from here: https://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/exe/